# Swift expression from Result success value falling back to error

Tags: swift

How can I get a value that is derived from Result's success value in the case of success or from an error value in the case of failure, without having to create a temporary variable?

Here's a working but verbose example of what I'm trying to do:

```swift
let result = Result<Int, Error>.success(1)

let displayText: String
switch result {
case let .success(value): displayText = String(value)
case let .failure(error): displayText = "Result not available. \(error)"
}

updateDisplayText(displayText)
```

I could get something close to what by converting the result to an optional value in the desired format, testing it with try operator, and using the nil-coalescing operator to provide the fallback.

```swift
updateDisplayText((try? result.map{ v in String(v) }.get()) ?? "Result not available.")
```

However, that approach doesn't access the failure's error. It also seems overly complex. Is there an approach that works with a single expression, similar to what can be done with an F# [match expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/match-expressions)?

Comment: So you want to say something like `let displayText = ...` directly?

Comment: declare `updateDisplayText(value.description)` in `success` case and `updateDisplayText("Result not available. \(error)")` in `failure` case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "match expressions" in Swift. As far as I know, if you want to match against enums with associated values, you must use some kind of *statement*, whether that's an `if case` or `switch` or whatever.

However, no one can stop you from putting that statement into a method, which you can then put inside an extension!

```
extension Result {
    func mapBoth<T>(success: (Success) -> T, error: (Failure) -> T) -> T {
        switch self {
        case .success(let s):
            return success(s)
        case .failure(let e):
            return error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

`updateDisplayText` can then be called like this:

```
updateDisplayText(result.mapBoth(
    success: { String($0) },
    failure: { "Result not available. \($0)" }
))
```